# Terrible Avatar and Going Loud

Tags: chronicles-of-darkness-2e, demon-the-descent

In FoH, p.116, Terrible Avatar let's you split from your demonic form and your Cover.  Would your cover still be blown if the demonic form then "Went Loud"?

The words, "leaving nothing for enemies to track back to the demon's Cover" is what gets me confused.

I would think that her Cover would be blown, but I can see it going either way.

The flip side would be, can you even GO LOUD when you are split?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the DtD Glossary on p.27, and in "Going Loud" on p.113, "going loud" is described as "entering demonic form".

Thus it seems to me, since Terrible Avatar prevents "entering demonic form", that you cannot "go loud" in that state.

Terrible Avatar: So long as the avatar lasts, the Unchained cannot take her demonic form.

Comment: Even in demon form a demon can Go Loud to obtain the other advantages of the process.

Comment: @KieranMullen Are you implying that on a Dramatic Failure your demon avatar could Go Loud as a precursor to attacking you? :) Nice but I think the avatar has no covers to consume.

Comment: There's no indication in RaW that Terrible Avatar prevents the PC from choosing to Go Loud. I'd rule that Going Loud supersedes the Exploit and the Cover is consumed. Of course your dramatic failure case would only come into play if your demon avatar was in danger of being vanquished by your Cover :-).

Answer (score 2):

"Going Loud"  does not result in the "Blown" condition. The Blown condition is (DtD p.119):

> The God-Machine knows your Cover is just that. It might not be actively hunting you, not yet anyway, but you can’t hide from it any longer. Even if you have multiple Cover identities, the God-Machine has your frequency and the only way to lose it is to destroy the compromised cover.

In this case your Cover still *exists*, but the GM knows that it is a Cover. In contrast, "Going Loud" consumes your current cover to fuel a variety of effects (DtD p.196):

> Going loud allows the demon to completely heal any lethal or bashing damage and shrug off any Tilts affecting her. In addition to this, when the demon goes loud, her current Cover is lost; she replenishes all her Aether, her Primum is set to 10, and she gains access to every Embed her Incarnation gives her affinity for along with all Exploits.

The DtD manual refers to burning the demon's Cover completely to fuel all of these effects.  It's not a question of being able to track a demon back to their original Cover, since that Cover no longer exists.  Without an additional Cover, the demon is stuck in its demon-form.

Using the "Terrible Avatar" Exploit may split the demon from its Cover, but subsequently "Going Loud" consumes the Cover to fuel further transformations.